# Visual Studio Item Template with Wizard

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am looking for a sample on how to create an item template with Wizard in Visual Studio 2010.
My requirement is when the user selects Add Item, I want to show a dialog where the user enters some input parameters. Then on pressing OK in the form we generate an XML file which we want to add to the project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you get the vsix featured in this link 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/04/creating-and-sharing-project-item-templates.aspx 
and rename it as a zip file and open it up to start with. however the xml in the Item Templates themselves aren't all that complicated. Looking at one I just generated with the tool for a classic asp file.

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>Classic ASP</DefaultName> 
    <Name>Classic ASP</Name>
    <Description>Adds script tag import ref</Description>
    <ProjectType>Web</ProjectType>
    <ProjectSubType>VisualBasic</ProjectSubType>
    <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References />
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.asp" ReplaceParameters="true">ClassicASP.asp</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```